# How to edit existing UI in IOS to display button in correct frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UI in `iOS` in which I have put a button inside a `UITableView`. I have set the X and Y  coordinates. But the button is overlapping with the textview. I have increased the y coordinate still there is no change.

[This is my X and Y coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYFWs.png)

[This is UI which I get in my device the add chemical is the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrCWB.jpg)

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b0xH.png)

I want the button below the text view.
Till now I have set the top constraint for the ESI textview using this code

```
[self.view addConstraints:@[ top]];
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ans6Text4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:100];
```

And for getting the button(_addChemical) in front I have used this code

```
[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront: _addChemical];
```

But none of this works.

Comment: set top constraint from ESI textView.

Comment: @Daljeet I have set top constraint using this code NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ans6Text4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:100];
[self.view addConstraints:@[ top]];

Comment: Still there is no change in my button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in some place you move `UITextField` in the front of a content view's hierarchy.
Look at your interface in debug mode. If you find your button under `UITextField`, add `[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront: button]`.
Or check `isHidden` property value of the button.
As I can see you have a correct layout.

Comment: I used code [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_addChemical]; and [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront: _addChemical]; still there is no change. And also there is no isHidden property for the button.

Comment: You add button into cell. _addChemic is subview of cell’s content view. Call the bring method inside cell: [self.contentView bring...]